# How can I pass an Array value in a function that will be used reference a JSON name in Pouchdb?

Tags: javascript, json, pouchdb

When I call the function below like this:

```
showTableTest("db", "testTable", "action", "context","projectName")
```

I want to use arguments[2] as the JSON name in the function (ie "action").

When the name is referenced directly like this:

```
 genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc.action + "</td>";
```

The correct values are returned

However when I referenced them like this:

```
  genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc.column[2] + "</td>";
```

I receive the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

How can I pass this value correctly?

```
function showTableTest (dbName,idOfTable) {
    var column = arguments;  
    var argNum = arguments.length;
    var genTable = "<table class='responsive'>";
    genTable+= "<tr>";
    for (var i=2,  tot=argNum; i < tot; i++) {
      genTable+= "<th>" + arguments[i] + "</th>"; 
    }
    genTable+= "</tr>";
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, attachments: true}).then(function (result) {
      for (var q=0,  tot=result.rows.length; q < tot; q++) {
        genTable+="<tr>";
        for (var c=2,  all=argNum; c < all; c++) {
          genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc.action + "</td>";
          genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc.column[2] + "</td>";
        }
        genTable+="</tr>";
      } 
      genTable+="</table>";
      document.getElementById(idOfTable).innerHTML = genTable;
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a demo how to call from json by key in `code snippet`, so your code

```
genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc.column[2] + "</td>";
```

shouled be changed to

```
genTable+="<td>" + result.rows[q].doc[column[1]] + "</td>";
```

```js
showTableTest("name", "id");
function showTableTest(dbName, idOfTable) {
    var column = arguments;
    var argNum = arguments.length;
    console.info(column[1]);//your idOfTable index is No 1
}
```

```
result.rows[q].doc[column[2]]
```

`column[2]` Is a key,you can call like this